# How do you set what time of day McAfee Security Scan Plus scans?

Tags: anti-virus

McAfee Security Scan Plus (can't tell the version, "About McAfee" directs me [here](http://us.mcafee.com/root/landingpages/affLandPage.asp?affid=739&lpname=Adobe_ni&aco=0&pfid=3&cid=70299&ss=1&rid=10&ths=&trj=&vir=&pup=&virc=&trjc=&pupc=&webd=&web=)) says on its settings page "Decide how often and when you want to scan", then provides only a drop-down saying "Every week", "Every other week", "Every month". How do I tell it to scan at 6am?  It looks to me as if there is no way.

Comment: OT: Install *real* virus protection ;)

Comment: You can schedule weekly scan

Comment: @BloodPhilia: it's a computer not controlled by me.  @Ankur: does that allow setting time of day?